# How to add call button to search result in CoreSpotlight?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, corespotlight

In WWDC session Introduction to Search APIs. They show a search result of Airbnb app with a call button. From what I saw I think the result was created with `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` not from Web Markup api.
I tried setting ItemContentType of `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` to `kUTTypeItem`, `kUTTypeMessage`, `kUTTypeEmailMessage` of course with phoneNumbers value. None of them seems to work. All detail I put are appear correctly, except for the call button.

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *attributeSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeItem];
attributeSet.title = @"Call me back";
attributeSet.contentDescription = @"Firstname Lastname\n14:36 - 30 January 2014";
attributeSet.phoneNumbers = @[@"+66827364538"];
attributeSet.accountHandles = @[@"+66827364538"];
```

If I were to use `kUTTypeContent`. The call button appears but all details are not. Just name of contact that I put in when create `CSPerson` object.

```
CSPerson *person = [[CSPerson alloc] initWithDisplayName:@"Theptai Intathep"
                                                     handles:@[@"+66827364538"]
                                            handleIdentifier:CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
attributeSet.authors = @[person];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`attributeSet.supportsPhoneCall = @(YES);`